# How to get everything in between these two strings?

Tags: javascript, regex, match

How can I get everything between these two strings?

`ATemp.runFunct( <I WANT EVERYTHING IN BETWEEN THESE TWO PARENS> ), // comment`

I want everything in between the parens above, with the outside strings as a constant.

I have tried multiple regex expressions, but they have not worked, such as:

`ATemp\.runFunct\(*.?\), \/\/ comment`

Any ideas?  Thanks! (PS, I'm using javascript)

Comment: `*.?` should be `.*?` You probably also want to use a capture group so that you can actually reference that part later on: `(.*?)`.

Comment: @FelixKling Thanks!  However, I still have no matches when I do `reg.exec(string)`, even though there is that exact pattern in the string...

Comment: Maybe it isn't. It works fine for your example: http://jsfiddle.net/KvmY2/.

Comment: @FelixKling http://jsfiddle.net/KvmY2/1/ when I alert it, you're right - I do get the result, but I also get the regex?  is my understanding of regex.exec incorrect, or should it just return the string?

Comment: Well, `exec` returns an array. The first element is the whole match, and the second element is the value of the first capture group. That's what you want. Do `alert(test[1])`.

Comment: @FelixKling ahh - thanks!  If you answer, I'll tick it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`*.?` should be `.*?`. Otherwise you are matching zero or more `(`. You probably also want to use a capture group so that you can actually reference that part later on: `(.*?)`

Example:

```
var match = /ATemp\.runFunct\((.*?)\), \/\/ comment/.exec('ATemp.runFunct( <I WANT EVERYTHING IN BETWEEN THESE TWO PARENS> ), // comment');
alert(match[1]);
```

[`.exec`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) returns an array, where the first element is the complete match and the second element is the value of the first capture group (and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/mikea80/kSuk4/

```
var str = "(Hello world!)";
var startIndex = str.indexOf("(");
var endIndex = str.indexOf(")");
var res = str.substring(startIndex + 1, endIndex); 
alert(res);
```